# Create Object coordinates from Object's Loc/Rot/Scale?

Tags: materials, node-editor, transforms, drivers

When you use a Texture Coordinate node's Object coordinates with an empty object selected in the dropdown, the transforms of the empty effect the texture its plugged into. You get the Object's Loc/Rot/Scale even though Object Coords are only a single Vector.

How does this work? And, how could it be recreated? If you used Attributes/Drivers to get an Object's Loc/Rot/Scale in the material nodes, what node setup would give the same behavior as using Object Texture Coordinates with the same Object?